# Reference Request: Factored Polynomials with Negative Integer Zeros and Divisor-Related Multiplicities

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, reference-request, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm interested in polynomials of the following form:

$$p_k(x)=\prod_{j=1}^k(x+j)^{\lfloor{\frac{k}{j}\rfloor}{}}$$

Outside any of my own analysis, I wondered if there is any name for these polynomials, if they have been studied before, if there are any papers written about properties of these polynomials.

EDIT:  Note that I wrote the original exponent incorrectly.  It should have been $k/j$ in the floor function

$$p_1(x)=(x+1)$$
$$p_2(x)=(x+1)^2(x+2)$$
$$p_3(x)=(x+1)^3(x+2)(x+3)$$
$$p_4(x)=(x+1)^4(x+2)^2(x+3)(x+4)$$
$$p_5(x)=(x+1)^5(x+2)^2(x+3)(x+4)(x+5)$$
$$p_6(x)=(x+1)^6(x+2)^3(x+3)^2(x+4)(x+5)(x+6)$$

Comment: It's neither a polynomial nor exponential function.  Compare with the function $x^{\lfloor x \rfloor}$.

Comment: I should mention that the input $x$ is discrete, domain is only positive integers.

Comment: @NgChungTak, I fixed it.  I had incorrectly supplied the input $x$ in the floor function where I wanted the upper bound $k$.